# How to render images without blocking UI?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this image rendering function that is is causing the main/UI thread to block/stutter when I render it.

What are ways to not block the thread and rendering on a different thread in iOS?  Are there native API's to help you?

Updated with code:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

function
{
    UIImage *shrinkedImage = [ThisClass imageWithImage:screenShotImage scaledToSize:shrinkImageToSize];

    UIImage * rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: shrinkedImage.CGImage
                                                        scale: 1.0
                                                  orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you're using to render the image.

Comment: Updated with code used to render.

Comment: Why are you resizing? if you just want to display it on the screen, use an image view and set it to scale, apply a rotation transform onto it and you're done in a couple of statements with reasonable performance.

Comment: How? I mean the rotation transform that is better than mines?  Thanks.

Comment: Well i need to resize and transform because the image i get is in landscape mode.  Show me some code that can quickly do this if you can.  Maybe I've been doing it the hard-way.

Comment: Why don't you rotate ur image using photoshop? You are doing a bit of overwork i think

Comment: No for photoshop because I get it from a link at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a coupe of things you could consider:

1. Check what's taking most of the time using the the `time profiler` of the `instruments tool`.
2. Make usage of `UIImageView` instead of `UIImage` to apply some transformation such as rotation and transform. You need to apply those transform to its CALayer of the UIImageView.
3. Put the loading of your image in a background thread using `GCD`. Here is an example:

> ```
> dispatch_queue_t preloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("preload queue", nil);
> dispatch_async(preloadQueue, ^{
>                                 UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:yourImageReferencePath];
>                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   
>                                                                           yourUIView.image = yourImage});
>                                                                           });
> dispatch_release(preloadQueue);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use GCD to perform your tasks in the background?

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // Do your computations in the global queue (background thread)
    UIImage *shrinkedImage = [ThisClass imageWithImage:screenShotImage scaledToSize:shrinkImageToSize];
    UIImage * rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: shrinkedImage.CGImage
                                                        scale: 1.0
                                                  orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
    // Once done, always do all your display operations to update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        yourImageView.image = rotatedImage;
    });
});
```

For more information, read Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1).